# Angular mentions custom dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I,m currently using Angular mentions library and trying to customize dropdown menu with mentioned names.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mentions?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

When I'm using items like:

```
   items: any[] = [{name: "Noah", email: "mail@gmail.com"}, {name:"Liam", mail: "mail1@gmail.com"}, {name:"Teo", mail: "mail1@gmail.com"}];
```

and in my html:

instead of `labelKey` I want to have more property then just name for example I want to have name and email.

Does anyone know how to achieve this with this angular-mentions library?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check [@flxng/mentions](https://github.com/seidme/flxng/tree/master/projects/mentions) library for Angular.

You can provide your own template for menu so it's completely custom.

It also supports many other features such as:

- Highlighting mentions
- Editing mentions
- Editing text which contains mentions (edit text mode)
- Events when a tag is clicked or hovered
- Events when a mention is selected or removed
- Providing the trigger character, etc.

Check [Github](https://github.com/seidme/flxng/tree/master/projects/mentions) for docs and demos.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use `label` for the value to be suggested.

```
items: any[] = [{label: "Noah", email: "mail@gmail.com"}, {label:"Liam", mail: "mail1@gmail.com"}, {label:"Teo", mail: "mail1@gmail.com"}];
```

Other than that, I don't think you can do what you needed using this library.
If you really want to use this library, a workaround would be using two objects for the same user, along with the same id.

```
items: any[] = [{label: "Noah", id: "user_id_1"}, {label: "mail1@gmail.com", id: "user_id_1"}, 
{label: "Liam", id: "user_id_2"}, {label: "mail2@gmail.com", id: "user_id_2"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, use [mentionConfig],
So, for name

```
<input type="text" [mention]="items" 
     [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',maxItems:10,labelKey:'name'}">
```

For email -take a look that your array has `mail` and `email` (use only email)-

```
<input type="text" [mention]="items" 
      [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',maxItems:10,labelKey:'email'}">
```

See [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mentions-ecnhsi?file=app/app.component.html)